# Convert string (System.String) to type

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to create a generic XML to object converter. In other words, the following is my XML

```
<setting>
   <name>testing</name> 
   <type>System.String</type>
   <defaultObj>TTTT</defaultObj>
</setting>
```

the type field holds the type of the object its loading back in. This is just the object structure I serailized in. Regardless, I am having an issue converting

```
System.String
```

into an actual type variable. So for instance, in order to convert I have the following code:

```
foreach (XNode node in document.Element(root).Nodes())
{
   T variable = new T(); //where T : new()

   foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
   {
      field.SetValue(variable, Convert.ChangeType(((XElement)node).Element(field.Name).Value, field.FieldType));
   }

   retainedList.Add(variable);
}
```

which obtains objects back in a generic way. The algorithm works perfectly until it comes across the Type field. I get a:

```
Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Type'.
```

run time error. From what I can tell it is having an issue directly converting a type identifier (string) directly into a type. I am not sure how to get around this issue, atleast when it comes to keeping things generic and clean. Any ideas? I am sorry if the issue is a bit vague, if you don't quite understand I will try to clarify further. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to convert the string `System.String` into the type `System.String`.

You can do that with `Type.GetType(string typeName);`

For example, the `type` variable below will have the `Type` object of `System.String`.

```
var type = Type.GetType("System.String");
```

You can then use that `Type` in the `Convert.ChangeType` overload you're using.

```
Convert.ChangeType(fieldValue, type);
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettype.aspx) which has a variety of overloads to maps type specified as string to `Type` instances.

Answer (score -8):

What needs to be said here in my opinion is that you should be quite a bit more familiar with programming in C# before you start tackling into serializers and deserializers. As suggested above this particular obstacle can be solved using the Type.GetType method, however I would point you in the direction of the [System.Xml.Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.aspx) namespace, where things like this are already solved and prepared for easy use.

Comment: I've been around C# for quite a while. In this case I have a lot of time on my hands. Word of advice; if you ever want to learn something really well, do it your own way. At worst you will lose time, but you will learn a lot compared to going the easy route.

Comment: lot of time on your hands? Well, lucky you :)